# Laravel paginate many to many relationship with eager and orderby

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm struggling paginating the results of a many-to-many relationship in Laravel. I want to paginate the combination: Not 1 course with 10 availabilities and inversed. I want 10 courses with 10 availabilities. Easy thing if you query the relation table, but I want to **order by a table's field** (availability date).

Database structure (simplified)

```
courses
  id - integer
  name - string

course_availability //relation table
  course_id - integer
  availability_id - integer

availability
  id - integer
  date - date
```

The Availability model has a scope with active dates and ordered by date, the courseAvailability relationship has this included.

Attempts:

**Availability view**
Problem: I get 1 availability with multiple courses (100+)

```
Availability::whereHas('courseAvailability', function ($q) use($course_ids) {
  $q->whereIn('courses_id', $course_ids);
})->with('courseAvailability' => function($q) use($course_ids) {
  $q->whereIn('courses_id', $course_ids);
}])->forPage(1, 10)->get();
```

**Course Availability view** Problem: Sorting on the 10 results, not on the actual data, the relationship values

```
CourseAvailability::whereIn('courses_id', $course_ids)
  ->whereIn('availability_id', $availability_ids)
  ->forPage(1, 10)->get()->sortBy('availability.date');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, what I was looking for was a simple [join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins) query.

Following worked for me:

```
$availability = 
   CourseAvailability::join('availability', 'availability.id', '=', 'course_availability.availability_id')
   ->where('availability.date', '>', date('Y-m-d'))
   ->orderBy('availability.date')
   ->whereIn('courses_id', $course_ids);
```

+processing:

```
$availability = $availability
      ->with(['course.options', 'availability.location.meta'])
      ->forPage($page, $perPage)->get()->flatten();
```